# https URL Rewrite rewrites to domain root, does not keep url structure

Tags: ssl, iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config, iis-7.5

I am trying to rewrite any url hit on http, to an https equivalent.

My rule rewrites to https, but it defaults back to the domain root, and does not keep the url structure.

I.e. http://www.domain.com/dir1 -> rewrites to -> https://www.domain.com , and not to https://www.domain.com/dir1

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
 </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the job...

```
<rewrite>
 <rules>


 <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
 </rule> 

 </rules>
</rewrite>
```